# Returning a field with an ampersand

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a strange problem while trying to get some data out of a MySQL database using PHP. Not sure if it matters, but encoding on database, connection and PHP file are all UTF-8. Heres my code:

```
$testcode = "Unique12345 & TestName";
$sql="
    Select
        dw_test.testID,
        dw_test.testText
    From
        dw_test
    Where
        dw_test.testCode = '".$testcode."'
";
if(!$qry = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) reporterror(mysqli_error($link), $sql, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'], __FILE__, __LINE__);
if(mysqli_num_rows($qry)>0){
    $test_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $resultTest = $test_array['testID'];
    $testText = $test_array['testText'];
}else{
    echo "Nothing found";
}
```

If I run that using PHP, it will say "Nothing found", but if I run it using Windows MySQL Workbench, it returns 1 record (the correct one). I suspect that it is the ampersand (&), because changing the query to something else that exists works fine.

I have tried escaping the & with a slash:

```
$testcode = str_replace("&","\&",$testcode);
```

and I have tried playing around with single and double quote combinations, but everything I try produces the same result

What am I doing wrong in my PHP? How come the Workbench tool works fine when using the same query?

Comment: 1. Use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the $testcode. 2. Consider switching to PDO instead of mysql as soon as possible. 3. What does `reporterror()` actually do?

Comment: reporterror is a custom function that emails me in case of errors. $testcode is passed through mysqli_real_escape_string() as part of a loop, I have just omitted it for simplicity. The code snippet works for other values of $testcode, it's only when it encounters an ampersand that it stops working.

Comment: So you're sure that your `mysqli_query()` doesn't throw any errors? Also, try `echo $sql` inside your script right after you form it, and then try it in the Workbench.

Comment: There are no errors with mysqli, it runs successfully and returns 0 rows. I have echo'd $sql and copied, pasted into the Workbench tool and it returns 1 row. So frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!
I added this in front of the sql query:

```
$testcode = str_replace("&amp;","&",$testcode);
```

Thanks for everyones help